# Outputting URLs with a custom route model binding key

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have the following setup:

routes.php

```
Route::get('{page?}', [
    'uses'=>'PageController@getPage',
    'as'=>'page'
])->where('page', '(.*)?');
```

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
$router->bind('page', function($value, $route)
{
    if($value == "/"){ $value = "home"; };
    $explodedPage = explode("/",$value);
    $page = Page::findBySlug(last($explodedPage));
    if(!isset($page)){
        \App::abort(404);
    }
    $ancestors = $page->ancestorsAndSelf()->get();
    $sections=array();
    foreach($ancestors as $ancestor)
    {
        $sections[]=$ancestor->slug;
    }
    if(implode("/",$sections)==$value){
        return $page;
    }else{
        return $page;
        //Else Redirect
    }
});
```

Page.php

```
use Baum\Node;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use URL;
use Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableInterface;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableTrait;

class Page extends Node implements SluggableInterface
{

    use RevisionableTrait, SoftDeletes, SluggableTrait;

    protected $sluggable = array(
        'build_from' => 'title',
        'save_to'    => 'slug',
    );

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'content', 'owner_id', 'system', 'status'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['parent_id','lft','rgt','depth'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from revision
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontKeepRevisionOf = ['updater_id','parent_id','lft','rgt','depth'];

}
```

URLS look like such:

```
localhost/ (uses pre-defined slug)  
localhost/page-slug  
localhost/parent-slug/page-slug  
localhost/parent-parent-slug/parent-slug/page-slug  
Etc...
```

Retrieving pages works fine; but my question is in regards to generating the URL

```
{{URL::route('page',$page)}}
```

Simply Generates,
    localhost/page-id

I know I can do:

```
{{URL::route('page',['page'=>$page->generateURLString()])}}
```

But I would much rather do this cleaner if possible. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you can do `{{URL::route('page',['page'=>$page->generateURLString()])}}` because `route('page',$page)` will return the patter name.

Then, my advice is, as you need some cleaner, to create a custom function extending the Route class or just declare it as a conventional function:

```
public function page($bind){
    return route('page', ['page' => $bind]);
}
```

Then just do:

```
{{ page($page->generateURLString()) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since version 5 you can now have a `getRouteKey()` on your `Model` (through `UrlRoutable`) that you can use to return your custom route key.
Something like:

```
class Page extends Node implements SluggableInterface
{
    //......

    public function getRouteKey() {
        return $this->generateURLString();
    }
}
```

To make `{{ route('page', $page) }}` behave as you'd like.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getRouteKey)